# Able to make a computer act as the CLIENT, but it can't act as a SERVER?

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, client-server, tcp, visual-c++-2017

I am running code:  SERVER on computerA and CLIENT on computerB.
However when I have them switch places: CLIENT on computerA and SERVER on computerB... no connection is made and it times out.  On the CLIENT, I do alter the IP address to the correct machine:  computerB.

What info do you guys need to understand more of the problem... let me know... thx

---

Edit:  So here is the FIREWALL:  DEFENDER:  I allowed my app(client1) total access... but still nothing when running in reverse or swap.

[image]

---

UPDATE: we now added computerC... computerC works with computerA as either the client or server. But it fails to act as a CLIENT to computerB as well. Works as a SERVER to computerB.  So the problem is computerB!!! I have no firewall running. ???   ...tried rebooting... but no change.  All firewalls disabled.

```
A=computerMainframe; B=computerJack;  C=computerMatt

compA(SERVER):compB(CLIENT):WORKS!
compA(CLIENT):compB(SERVER):FAILS!

compB(CLIENT):compB(SERVER):WORKS!  Forcing through the router:

compC(SERVER):compB(CLIENT):WORKS!
compC(CLIENT):compB(SERVER):FAILS!

compA(SERVER):compC(CLIENT):WORKS!  <--
compA(CLIENT):compC(SERVER):WORKS!  <--
```

Comment: Sounds like computerB has a firewall running?  Try disabling the firewall then trying again.

Comment: but it lets it work the otherway?

Comment: added DEFENDER screen shot

Comment: Firewalls block incoming TCP connections, but allow outgoing TCP connections.  Disable the firewall entirely as shown at the following link, then try your test again.  https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-firewall-2624505

Comment: Thank you... that is a BIG deal to know.... however in this puzzle, it made NO difference.   NOTE:  I was able to run both the SERVER and CLIENT on the same machine... forcing it to go through the router.

Comment: UPDATE:  we now added computerC... computerC works with computerA as either the client or server.  So the problem is computerB!!! I have no firewall running. ???